# Error - Cannot feed value of shape X for Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've run all the examples on the `Tensorflow` page, using the MNIST database. Now I'm trying to run my own example and I really just don't get it.

Say I have this csv table:

[image]

It has like 5000 rows. and the last column is the label for each row, this one is composed of multiple features.
Now for my first concrete example. I want to train a NN on this data, for that here what I've done:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import  numpy as np
    import  csv
    import os
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
    # read training data
    Training_file  = open('onetest.csv', 'r', newline='')
    reader = csv.reader(Training_file)
    row = next(reader)
    number_of_rows = 2431
    x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,len(row[:-1])])
    w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(row[:-1]),25]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]))
    model = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w),b)
    y_ = tf.placeholder('float',[25,None])
    y =  tf.nn.softmax(model)

    cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    index =1
    batch_xs =[]
    batch_ys= []
    for row in reader:
        batch_xs.append(row[:-1])
        batch_ys.append(row[-1])
        print(len(batch_xs),len(batch_ys))
        index +=1
        if index%10==0:
            sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_:batch_ys})
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))
            batch_xs.clear();
            batch_ys.clear();
```

Here is there error that I get :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4dbaa38c4d9c> in <module>()
     29     index +=1
     30     if index%10==0:
---> 31         sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_:batch_ys})
     32         correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
     33         accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    765     try:
    766       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 767                          run_metadata_ptr)
    768       if run_metadata:
    769         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    942                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
    943                 'which has shape %r'
--> 944                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    945           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
    946             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (9,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_17:0', which has shape '(25, ?)'
```

I've change the value of the index but it didn't solve it so I guess I'm misunderstanding something. will be grateful for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this row `y_ = tf.placeholder('float',[25,None])`, `y_` is defined to be a placeholder for data that has 25 rows (and any number of columns). Then in your code, due to the row `if index%10==0:` your `batch_ys` has 10 rows, which is the reason that you get this error.

Comment: thanks Mirian for  replying. I 've posted my answer ! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So I got it, here is the cod for that, it may help somebody out there :

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import  numpy as np
import  csv
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
# read training data
Training_file  = open('onetest.csv', 'r', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(Training_file)
row = next(reader)

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,len(row[:-1])])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(row[:-1]),25]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]))
model = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w),b)
y_ = tf.placeholder('float',[None,25])
y =  tf.nn.softmax(model)
print(y)

cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
index =0
batch_xs =[]
ys= []
for row in reader:
    batch_xs.append(row[:-1])
    ys.append(row[-1])

    index +=1
    if index%25==0:
            batch_ys = np.reshape(ys,(1,25))

            sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs,y_:batch_ys})
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))
            print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:batch_xs,y_:batch_ys}))
            batch_xs.clear()
            ys.clear()
```